# How to disable emoji button in keyboard by using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to disable the emoji button on the Android keyboard.

[image: tt]

Answer (score 2):

I also want to disable emoji button in keyboard in my app so, I have achieve this by adding  keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword in TextField.

```
TextField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
          showCursor: true,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
          decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none)
 )
```

Comment: it worked on entering emoji, but not work when copy emoji and paste in TextField..